kafka + undertsanding better the kafka controller.log logs
we have cluster with 12 Kafka machines and 3 zookeeper servers on Linux servers

Kafka version is 2.7 version , ( broker and controller are co-hosted on the same PID )

as known Kafka have 2 important logs and they are server.log and controller.log
about controller.log  , when we look on this log we can see the following words - "Shutdown completed" in the log
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,582] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread) 

the first thinking when we see the messages about "Shutdown completed" - is like this message is "bad" and why controller stopped ...
but when we look on all machines most of the machines have this message as - Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
but on other hand only one controller should be active from all brokers and maybe the messages as "Shutdown completed" are only indicate that controllers that are not active are in standby state and therefore are in state of - Shutdown completed ?
for example - here one of the log from one broker machine
[2024-08-20 21:23:18,084] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Broker 1007 was elected as controller instead of broker 1001 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ControllerMovedException: Controller moved to another broker. Aborting controller startup procedure
[2024-08-20 21:33:51,281] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Broker 1005 was elected as controller instead of broker 1001 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ControllerMovedException: Controller moved to another broker. Aborting controller startup procedure

[2024-08-20 21:42:01,581] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Shutting down (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)

[2024-08-20 21:42:01,582] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,582] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Stopped (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,582] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Resigning (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,583] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Unregister BrokerModifications handler for Set() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,604] INFO [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=1001] Stopped partition state machine (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,608] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=1001] Stopped replica state machine (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2024-08-20 21:42:01,608] INFO [Controller id=1001] Resigned (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2024-08-20 21:43:45,196] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Starting (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2024-08-20 21:43:45,208] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Broker 1005 has been elected as the controller, so stopping the election process. (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2024-08-20 21:52:28,400] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Broker 1001 was elected as controller instead of broker 1001 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ControllerMovedException: Controller moved to another broker. Aborting controller startup procedure
<---- LOG IS ENDED HERE

so the question is - can we ignore the messages as INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=1001] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
of maybe something is wrong with the Kafka controller ?
